# tinyMCE.get("content") is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I get this message : `tinyMCE.get("message_data_" + msg_id) is undefined` on Firebug after
I click on the button to submit the form.

`msg_id` *is* defined, I checked it. `message_data_` is also defined.
The function `tinyMCE.get` is not for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using one single editor instance you may use `tinymce.editors[0]` instead of `tinyMCE.get("message_data_" + msg_id)`.

Comment: is it supposed to be `tinyMCE`? And I still cannot fix mine.

Comment: tinymce in lowercases is the correct way. you may also use tinymce.activeEditor

Comment: To those having this issue, another way of finding out what available tinymce methods (and proper casing for each) is to use firebug to break where you want to call this get method, and explore available functions within the tinyMCE type. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have control over init method of TinyMCE then, you can follow this solution. Basically it adds a fallback if TinyMCE is not initialized.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function myCustomSetContent( id, content ) {
        // Check if TinyMCE is defined or not.
        if( typeof tinymce != "undefined" ) {
            var editor = tinymce.get( id );
            // Check if TinyMCE is initialized properly or not.
            if( editor && editor instanceof tinymce.Editor ) {
                editor.setContent( text );
                editor.save( { no_events: true } );
            } else {
                // Fallback
                // If TinyMCE is not initialized then directly set the value in textarea.
                //TinyMCE will take up this value when it gets initialized.
                jQuery( '#'+id ).val( text );
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function myCustomGetContent( id ) {
        // Check if TinyMCE is defined or not.
        if( typeof tinymce != "undefined" ) {
            var editor = tinymce.get( id );
            // Check if TinyMCE is initialized properly or not.
            if( editor && editor instanceof tinymce.Editor ) {
                return editor.getContent();
            } else {
                // Fallback
                // If TinyMCE is not initialized then directly set the value in textarea.
                // TinyMCE will take up this value when it gets initialized.
                return jQuery( '#'+id ).val();
            }
        }
        return '';
    }

    $(".class-to-update-content").on("click", function(e) {
        myCustomSetContent( "tinymce-editor-id", "New Content in Editor" );
    });

    $(".class-to-get-content").on("click", function(e) {
        $("div.class-to-display-content").html( myCustomGetContent( "tinymce-editor-id" ) );
    });
});
```

Ref : http://blog.incognitech.in/tinymce-undefined-issue/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using multiple editor in a form then you can create a function and get its value 
i.e.

```
// Declare a function to get editor value
function tinyMca_text(field_id) {

 if ( jQuery("#"+field_id+":hidden").length > 0)
 {
 return tinyMCE.get(field_id).getContent();
 }
 else
 {
  return jQuery('#'+field_id).val();
 }

}

// show that value

console.log(tinyMca_text('field'));
```